# after deleting an object saved in coredata the object persists in the previous tableViewController

Tags: ios, core-data

i am new to coredata. I have got
1. a mainview controller where i enter and save the data in corresponding entities created in coredata.
2. Then i have a tableview(totalTableView) controller where it shows the user entered data collectively, after this
3. there is another tableview (todaysTableView) which shows  data entered in the current day only.

All are connected by navigation controller. When i delete an object from todaysTableView it disappears then and there itself but when i navigate back to totalTableView the object is still there. Also when i navigate all the way back to my mainview controller(home screen) and then i go to my totalTableView the deleted object is not there and now its cleared and now its perfect. Why its not getting cleared when i immediately navigates back to totalTableView after deletion.
flow of my viewcontrollers are like this

mainViewController-->totalTableView-->todaysTableView

here is my code in the todaysTableView m.file to delete the object with its object id

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    // Delete the row from the data source


    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[managedObjectContext objectWithID:moID]];

    [managedObjectContext save:nil];

    NSLog(@"object id check %@",moID);

    NSError *error = nil;

    if(![managedObjectContext save:&error])

    {
        NSLog(@"deleting error");

        return;
    }

    [self.todaysCategory removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationFade)];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

If anyone could guide me to fix this. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use a NSFetchedResultsController for your table views? - If not: have a look at it!

Comment: UITableView reloadData.

Comment: @MartinR i didnt use NSFetchedResultsController. that is the cause of my problem rit?

Comment: @HotLicks i have tried that. its not working. thanks for replying

Comment: Then you didn't do it right.  You probably have some side table that is retaining the data.

Comment: @HotLicks i have got some float value calculations in that table view to print that as subtitle in the tableViewcell, so when i reload tableView data those values of those floats get doubled.

Comment: @HotLicks i didn't get that side table idea, can you explain. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TotalTableView holds some NSManagedObjects in memory, which it fetches when it is initialised.
Core data has mechanisms to notify totalTableView when objects are deleted, but you have to use them.

For your totalTableView to remove objects from it's display as you delete them, you have to respond to the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Register with the default notification centre to receive this and you'll get notified by the context when objects change.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification) {
    // Either reload your data, or respond case by case.
}];
```

From the documentation : The notification object is the managed object context. The userInfo dictionary contains the following keys: NSInsertedObjectsKey, NSUpdatedObjectsKey, and NSDeletedObjectsKey.

Comment: thanks for the answer but actually i don't know how to use this in my code

Comment: That depends on how you fetch your data in totalTableView.

This code registers a block to be executed whenever objects are changed.  You should put this somewhere like viewDidLoad.  

The contents of the block have to reload the data from the editing context, and tell the tableView to reloadData.  You can either do this by refetching, or you can use the dictionary keys to get the object ids of the deleted or added objects and just adjust your in memmory structure.

Comment: i have tried notification method and reloaded the tableview but still too the deleted object is there until i restart my app. Actually i am deleting object from 2nd-tableview and when i navigate back to 1st tableview the data is there in the 1st tableview until i restart my app.

Comment: OK, so now you need to check where the data is being held.  It is cached in the core data object model, and in the tableView itself.
The tableView will only reload it's data when it gets [tableView reloadData] ( or one of the more specific reload cell commands).

You should be calling [tableview reloadData] from your notification handler, after you've updated/refetched the object map.


So what you need to do is put a break point in tableView:cellFor.. to see if that is being called.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509053/reloading-tableview-as-per-notification-after-deletion-of-object-in-coredata-sho) this is how i fetch data to populate my tableview.